# Error while publishing in R pubs

Tags: r, ssl, pubs

When I am trying to  publish my work in R Pubs I am getting an error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Calls: rpubsUpload ... <Anonymous> -> .postForm -> .Call -> <Anonymous> -> fun
Execution halted
```

Is there anyway to resolve it ?

Answer (score 16):

Add an .Rprofile file in the directory you are sending from and place this line:

```
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")
```

in the [`.Rprofile` or `RProfile.site`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/Startup) files.

Comment: Really you just need to run that line.  The .Rprofile makes it so you don't have to remember to do that in the future.  But note that if you take this route you have to either run that line or restart R for the .Rprofile to take effect.

Comment: I'm not sure on this.  I almost think the .Rprofile is necessary but can't remember.  It was a Windows problem I believe.  But the best way is for the user to try it and see.  I found the answer on RStudio's help list serve a while back so this should be searchable.

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar problem. I copied the `options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")` as described by @Tyler Rinker at the end of the .RProfile. The `.RProfile` file was located in `\library\base\R` folder of installation directory.

Comment: You can make a .Rprofile where ever you want.  This may or may not be something the user wants to set globally.  By making your own .Rprofile in that directory the change is local only (which may not be desired).

Answer (score 2):

I had also the same error message.
I found solution for my problem on [Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202448223-Publish-to-rpubs-Error-in-readBin-conn-what-raw-n-contentLength-invalid-n-argument) page.

In short, I added:

```
options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal")
options(RCurlOptions = list(verbose = FALSE, capath = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))
```

to `R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site`.
And do not forget to change permissions for this file.

My system:

```
sysname    release  machine 
"Windows"  "7 x64"  "x86-64" 

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an account in Rpubs. Also i have copied options(rpubs.upload.method = "internal") in .RProfile as suggested above and after doing that i just ran my .Rmd file and then published and it works fine.